# NPM lockfiles/shrinkwrap get random "dl" parameter tacked on to the "resolved" URL

Tags: npm, artifactory, lockfile, npm-shrinkwrap

Our company uses an Artifactory repository for storing internally-published packages and as a proxy for the NPM registry. Sometimes the `resolved` field in lockfiles/shrinkwrap files is as expected, containing URLs for our internal repository, but occasionally they show up as something like this (line break added for clarity):

```
https://our.repository.com/artifactory/api/npm/some-repo/lodash/-/lodash-3.10.1.tgz
  ?dl=https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-3.10.1.tgz
```

Then, from pull request to pull requests, these `dl` parameters constantly oscillate to being present or removed depending on which developer does an `npm install`, leading to a lot of pull request & commit noise.

I'm guessing it's Artifactory that's adding this `dl` param, since I fail to see it in a code search in the npm code base.

Why does this happen? Can we disable this behavior? And is it safe to strip this parameter as a `postshrinkwrap` script workaround?

Comment: Hey Jacob! did you progress on that by any chance?

Comment: Nope, it's still a mystery. Will try a bounty.

Comment: @ciekawy: What's your setup? Maybe there's some common elements with our org that will help us narrow it down?

Comment: We're just suffering from this as a dev team so I am not sure about the artifactory setup. Raised that on our company slack - will follow up upon any new info.

Comment: I am having this same problem with my company's artifactory as well.

Comment: I am also using Artifactory and we are having the same issue. Does anyone have found what causes the dl params to be appended depending on the developer? Is there a solution even partial?

Comment: I also have this problem with artifactory. Version 6.3.4.

Comment: Also hitting this, and starting a bounty for more visibility. Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Also experiencing this issue - just commenting to get notifications in case anybody discovers a root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of your problem is likely caching.

NPM caches packages that have been downloaded, so they don't have to be downloaded again, and they can even be re-installed offline if necessary. It also caches the resolved value for later use. If a package of the same version has already been resolved and downloaded, it doesn't need to go and fetch it again and get the updated download/resolved URL.

You can manually clear this cache with the following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Alternately, it could be that difference in how different versions of NPM calculate the resolved field are to blame (following the Location header or not). However I think caching is more-likely to blame.